# Why does jQuery wrap XHR object creation in try / catch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

If I had to write my own cross-browser AJAX function without jQuery (which I do), I would do this:

```
var getXHR = function() {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  }
}
```

But while digging through jQuery's [source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js), I noticed this:

```
function createStandardXHR() {
  try {
    return new window.XMLHttpRequest();
  } catch( e ) {}
}
function createActiveXHR() {
  try {
    return new window.ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" );
  }
}
```

Then:

```
createStandardXHR() || createActiveXHR();
```

Why do the jQuery developers just call the object constructors directly inside of a `try/catch` block, rather than using feature detection. I imagine a [`try/catch`](http://flippinawesome.org/2013/09/30/rethinking-javascripts-trycatch/) is slower than a simple `if` check. What is the benefit?

Comment: I other languages (java for example) a `try/catch` is usually faster than a `if`, especially when there's no exception.

Comment: BTW, do you really have to support browsers without `XMLHttpRequest` in a library you write in 2014 ?

Comment: Yes. Third-party JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is good.
After reading the code, I think the developers of jQuery uses this trick to create the Request object and test `!this.isLocal && /^(get|post|head|put|delete|options)$/i.test( this.type ) &&` in a single statement without error.

Comment: Nice. Also, I suspect this is a trade-off. A failing try/catch is slower than an if/else, but that block should only fail in a small percentage of cases.

Comment: @ggundersen: No, first you go through the method 'standard' (not IE) and then by the IE, or IE remains important in browsers, so the first method might often fail. :)